# Mount a hardware RAID in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, raid10

I added a hardware RAID to my server. It was configured with the LSI-MR9361-8i as a 87TiB RAID 10.

`sudo fdisk -l` returns:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 87.3 TiB, 96009698934784 bytes, 23439867904 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disklabel type: dos Disk identifier: 0x00005cd0

Device     Boot    Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type /dev/sdb1  *        2048    1050623    1048576   512M fd Linux raid autodetect /dev/sdb2        1050624    1052671       2048     1M 83 Linux /dev/sdb3        1052672   17829887   16777216     8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris /dev/sdb4       17829888 2000408575 1982578688 945.4G  5 Extended /dev/sdb5       17831936 2000408575 1982576640 945.4G fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/sdc: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disklabel type: dos Disk identifier: 0x0001d3a4

Device     Boot    Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type /dev/sdc1  *        2048    1050623    1048576   512M fd Linux raid autodetect /dev/sdc2        1050624    1052671       2048     1M 83 Linux /dev/sdc3        1052672   17829887   16777216     8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris /dev/sdc4       17829888 2000408575 1982578688 945.4G  5 Extended /dev/sdc5       17831936 2000408575 1982576640 945.4G fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/md1: 945.2 GiB, 1014945021952 bytes, 1982314496 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disklabel type: dos Disk identifier: 0x3ccf318f

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type /dev/md1p1              63 1445673284 1445673222 689.4G 83 Linux /dev/md1p2      1445673285 1982308544  536635260 255.9G  5 Extended /dev/md1p5      1445673348 1982308544  536635197 255.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/md0: 512 MiB, 536805376 bytes, 1048448 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

When I go to mount /dev/sda with `sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt/UB_RAID` I get the following error.

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Obviously, I want the 87TiB, but what is happening here? I should be able to mount this quite easily.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to create a filesystem on the block device before you can mount it.

For example:

```
mkfs.xfs /dev/sda
```

Comment: thank you. I ran `parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt` and `sudo parted /dev/sda mkpart primary ext4 0G 87TB`. I then ran your command above and it worked. Thanks again.